# How do I get the microarray data?

Tags: python-3.x

thank you for your help. I want to use the following python code, to read and process data from an affymetrix microarray data set. I want to elucidate differential gene expression in disease conditions of Crohn's disease and Ulcerative colitis, in mononuclear cells. The code runs perfectly, but when I try to see the content of X, I get an empty array at the output (like this : array([], dtype=float64)), which of course is not useful. Here is a link to the raw data set : https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/GDSbrowser?acc=GDS1615
I have tried long to figure out why I have an empty and unprocessable output, but to no avail. Here is the code:

```
import gzip
import numpy as np

"""
Read in a SOFT format data file.  The following values can be exported:

GID : A list of gene identifiers of length d
SID : A list of sample identifiers of length n
STP : A list of sample descriptions of length d
X   : A dxn array of gene expression values
"""
#path to the data file
fname = "../data/GDS1615_full.soft.gz"

## Open the data file directly as a gzip file
with gzip.open(fname) as fid:
    SIF = {}
    for line in fid:
        if line.startswith(line, len("!dataset_table_begin")):
            break
        elif line.startswith(line, len("!subject_description")):
            subset_description = line.split("=")[1].strip()
        elif line.startswith(line, len("!subset_sample_id")):
            subset_ids = [x.strip() for x in subset_ids]
            for k in subset_ids:
                SIF[k] = subset_description
    ## Next line is the column headers (sample id's)
    SID = next(fid).split("\t")

    ## The column indices that contain gene expression data
    I = [i for i,x in enumerate(SID) if x.startswith("GSM")]

    ## Restrict the column headers to those that we keep
    SID = [SID[i] for i in I]

    ## Get a list of sample labels
    STP = [SIF[k] for k in SID]

    ## Read the gene expression data as a list of lists, also get the gene
    ## identifiers
    GID,X = [],[]
    for line in fid:

        ## This is what signals the end of the gene expression data
        ## section in the file
        if line.startswith("!dataset_table_end"):
            break

        V = line.split("\t")

        ## Extract the values that correspond to gene expression measures
        ## and convert the strings to numbers
        x = [float(V[i]) for i in I]

        X.append(x)
        GID.append(V[0] + ";" + V[1])
X = np.array(X)

## The indices of samples for the ulcerative colitis group
UC = [i for i,x in enumerate(STP) if x == "ulcerative colitis"]

## The indices of samples for the Crohn's disease group
CD = [i for i,x in enumerate(STP) if x == "Crohn's disease"]
```

At the console, I get such output:
X
Out[94]: array([], dtype=float64)

X.shape
Out[95]: (0,)

Thank you once more for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This worked perfectly:

```
    import gzip
    import numpy as np


    """
    Read in a SOFT format data file.  The following values can be exported:

    GID : A list of gene identifiers of length d
    SID : A list of sample identifiers of length n
    STP : A list of sample desriptions of length d
    X   : A dxn array of gene expression values
    """
    #path to the data file
    fname = "../data/GDS1615_full.soft.gz"

    ## Open the data file directly as a gzip file
    with gzip.open(fname) as fid:
        SIF = {}
        for line in fid:
            if line.startswith(b"!dataset_table_begin"):
                break
            elif line.startswith(b"!subset_description"):

                subset_description = line.decode('utf8').split("=")[1].strip() 
            elif line.startswith(b"!subset_sample_id"):
                subset_ids = line.decode('utf8').split("=")[1].split(",")
                subset_ids = [x.strip() for x in subset_ids]
                for k in subset_ids:
                    SIF[k] = subset_description
        ## Next line is the column headers (sample id's)
        SID = next(fid).split(b"\t")
        ## The column indices that contain gene expression data
        I = [i for i,x in enumerate(SID) if x.startswith(b"GSM")]
        ## Restrict the column headers to those that we keep
        SID = [SID[i] for i in I]
        ## Get a list of sample labels   
        STP = [SIF[k.decode('utf8')] for k in SID]
    ## Read the gene expression data as a list of lists, also get the gene
    ## identifiers
    GID,X = [],[]
    for line in fid:
        ## This is what signals the end of the gene expression data
        ## section in the file
        if line.startswith(b"!dataset_table_end"):
            break
        V = line.split(b"\t")
        ## Extract the values that correspond to gene expression measures
        ## and convert the strings to numbers
        x = [float(V[i]) for i in I]
        X.append(x)
        GID.append(V[0].decode() + ";" + V[1].decode())

X = np.array(X)
## The indices of samples for the ulcerative colitis group
UC = [i for i,x in enumerate(STP) if x == "ulcerative colitis"]
## The indices of samples for the Crohn's disease group
CD = [i for i,x in enumerate(STP) if x == "Crohn's disease"]
```

results:

X.shape
Out[4]: (22283, 127)